# How to create multi select within select box in views expose filter in Drupal?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view with exposed filter. It's working correct. But I need to use select box in exposed filter with multiselect.

Answer (score 1):

User [Better Exposed Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), this module will give exact thing.

ok then in  Exposed form style -> BEF Settings ->

[image]

Comment: I am using this module. but this is not giving me multiselect option within selectlist.

Comment: then we use allow multiple sections then its dont give me select list

Comment: could you please elaborate more?

Comment: yes sure.. I need simple selectlist and option should have checkbox.. then I could select multiple option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have multiple values set in your exposed filter.. Chosen is quite a nice UI for select lists. Not a checkbox but it has a search and shift click.